# Renaming Files in Subdirectories using file path

Tags: python-3.x

**Scenario:** I am trying to Rename all .txt file named "a.txt" in all subfolders of a directory.

**Question:** I came up with the following code, but it has and issue: My loops don't work as expected, I was hoping to get the directory loop, to use the last part of the path, and use that string to rename the file. Right now, my code will rename the file with the latest directory name. How can this be fixed?

**Code:**

```
import os
import fnmatch

directory = "C:/Users/DGMS/Desktop/Test"

for root, subdirectories, files in os.walk(directory):
    for subdirectory in subdirectories:
        pathtest = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root, subdirectory)))
        print(pathtest)
    for file in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'a.txt'):
            os.rename(os.path.join(root, file),(os.path.join(root, pathtest)))
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Comment: change root to subdirectories in the 3rd for-loop (2nd inner for-loop)

Comment: @Joshua Thanks for the comment, but that has the same effect: it only uses the last available directory for the list in the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better code for what you want. All "a.txt" now  becomes "b.txt"

```
import os
rootdir = 'C:/Users/sid/Desktop/test'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if file == "a.txt"
        os.rename(os.path.join(subdir, file),os.path.join(subdir, "b.txt"))
```